# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} $ be given by $f(x) = x^3 -2$. Find $f^{-1}$.

Tags: functions

In the book titled: Discrete Mathematical Structures, by Tremblay; it is stated as Q.#3 in Ex. 2-4.3:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} $ be given by $f(x) = x^3 -2$. Find $f^{-1}$.

As per the book's notation, the inverse function should be denoted by $\tilde{f}(x) = \{<x^3 -2,x>| x \in \mathbb{R}\}.$ 
This leads to idea that as : $f(x)\circ \tilde{f}(x) = \mathbb{I}$, so $\tilde{f}(x) = \frac{\mathbb{I}}{f(x)}$.

Cannot pursue further, although the book has statements to aid in finding inverse by stating that if the original function $f(x)$ is a bijective one, then inverse is a function too. But, cannot use that too.

---

*Update* Based on inputs by @Elnur, $f^{-1}(y)=  <x^3 -2>\to x \,\,|\,\, x \in \mathbb{R}.$ Also, taking his notation, $y = <x^2-3>$.

> So, need find : $y = (f^{-1}(y))^3 - 2$.

Also, this leads to modification of OP's statement above to : $f(x)\circ \tilde{f}(y) = \mathbb{I}$

---

*Update 2 :* I have an idea to take a small set of values of $x$ for $f(x)$, & then finding out if can figure out inverse based on that.

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc}
  x&y\\
  0&-2\\
  1&-1\\
  2&6\\
\end{array}
\right] $$
But seems like it will fit only either with a program, in order to find the polynomial function; or for plotting a small number of inputs.

Comment: A function $f$ has inverse $g$ if $f(x) = y \iff g(y) = x$ for each $x$ in the domain of $f$ and each $y$ in the domain of $g$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Do I need to modify the highlighted part of *Update* above to : So, need find : $x = (f^{-1}(y))^3 - 2$.

Comment: Please type in complete sentences and do not use abbreviation. This is not a reminder to yourself.

Comment: @edm  I hope it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to define the inverse of a function $f$.

**Definition.**  Let $f: A \to B$ be a bijective function.  A function $g: B \to A$ is said to be the *inverse function* of $f$ if 
\begin{align*}
(g \circ f)(x) & = x && \text{for each $x \in A$}\\
(f \circ g)(x) & = x && \text{for each $x \in B$}
\end{align*}
For the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^3 - 2$, if we set $y = x^3 - 2$, then solving for $x$ in terms of $y$ gives 
\begin{align*}
y & = x^3 - 2\\
y + 2 & = x^3\\
\sqrt[3]{y + 2} & = x
\end{align*}
If we now interchange the variables to make $x$ the subject, we obtain 
$$y = \sqrt[3]{x + 2}$$
We will show that the function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x) = \sqrt[3]{x + 2}$ is $f^{-1}$.

Observe that for each $x \in \mathbb{R} = \text{Dom}_f$,
\begin{align*}
(g \circ f)(x) & = g(f(x))\\
               & = g(x^3 - 2)\\
               & = \sqrt[3]{x^3 - 2 + 2}\\
               & = \sqrt[3]{x^3}\\
               & = x
\end{align*}
and that for each $x \in \mathbb{R} = \text{Dom}_g$,
\begin{align*}
(f \circ g)(x) & = f(g(x))\\
               & = f(\sqrt[3]{x + 2})\\
               & = \sqrt[3]{x + 2}^3 - 2\\
               & = x + 2 - 2\\
               & = x
\end{align*}
so $g = f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Usually $f^{-1}(y)$ denotes [inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) . If it is the case here, then you need to solve equation $y = (f^{-1}(y))^3 - 2$.

Upd: $y = (f^{-1}(y))^3 - 2 \Rightarrow (f^{-1}(y))^3 = y + 2 \Rightarrow f^{-1}(y) = \sqrt[3]{y+2} $

Comment: Please help solve it.

Comment: @jiten: You need to solve it for $f^{-1}(y)$.

Answer (score 1):

You are given $f(x)=y$ and are to find $\tilde f(y)=x$. So basically you must express $x$ in terms of $y$ given the original relation:
$$
y=x^3-2
$$
So the question becomes how to solve this for $x$ (isolate $x$). I would start by adding $2$ to both sides, and some kind of root might come in handy.